# GNU Parallel multiple sets of commands

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'd like to use GNU Parallel to run the same command with two different parameters and two different globs. For example, I want the following jobs to run:

```
mycmd A apples1
mycmd A apples2
mycmd A apples3
mycmd B bananas1
mycmd B bananas2
```

I can do it with two separate calls, but this defeats the purpose of having my jobs managed by one call to `parallel`. Is there a way?

```
parallel mycmd A ::: apples*
parallel mycmd B ::: bananas*
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want Bs with your apples. Otherwise it is as simple as:

```
parallel mycmd ::: [A-Z] ::: [a-z]*
```

If A can be computed as the first char of the second arg, you can from version 20140722 do this:

```
parallel mycmd '{= $_=uc(substr($_,0,1)) =}' {} ::: [a-z]*
```

If you have a list of apples and the corresponding As like this:

```
A,apples1
A,apples2
B,bananas1
B,bananas2
B,bananas3
```

then you can split on ,:

```
cat file | parallel --colsep , mycmd {1} {2}
```

If this is also not how you have your input, then you need to explain a bit more about how you have your As and apples.

Comment: Correct, I don't want `B`s with the apples. `A` cannot be computed from the other arguments; what I've been doing right now is manually constructing the list as a file as you did in your final example.